# Replace nginx text on default nginx error pages

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

How it's possible to replace this text [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M65Vl.png) with custom one on every default nginx error page?

Comment: Just grab the default nginx error page and change the footer? That won't change much of anything but if that's your thing...

Comment: Where can I find the default nginx error page template

Answer (score 0):

Copy contents of the current error page by visiting the error page and in most browsers pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

Paste the contents into a new file, `502.html`, and remove or replace the offending portions of the new file.

Place `502.html` in the `root` directory for the `server` (e.g., `/var/www/html`, `/var/www/example.com/public/`, etc.).

In the desired `location` or `server`, or even under `http`, add:

```
error_page 502 /502.html;
```

There may be other or better ways to accomplish the same described in the
[error_page](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) documentation.

Comment: Yes but I dont want just one error page. I want to replace all default nginx pages with custom one

Comment: The linked `error_page` explains you can do this for every error code, exactly as in my answer, just replace `502` with the desired code.